# How to get a list of files in a folder in which the files are sorted with modified date time?

Tags: c++, boost

I need to a list of files in a folder and the files are sorted with their modified date time.

I am working with C++ under Linux, the Boost library is supported.

Could anyone please provide me some sample of code of how to implement this?

Comment: How does this differ from your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279164/cboost-file-system-to-return-a-list-of-files-older-than-a-specific-time? Nabulke has provided you with an answer that should point you in the right direction. From there it's not too hard to add the files to a vector and to sort them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++:boost file system to return a list of files older than a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279164/cboost-file-system-to-return-a-list-of-files-older-than-a-specific-time)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Most operating systems do not return directory entries in any particular order.  If you want to sort them (you probably should if you are going to show the results to a human user), you need to do that in a separate pass.  One way you could do that is to insert the entries into a `std::multimap`, something like so:

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
fs::path someDir("/path/to/somewhere");
fs::directory_iterator end_iter;

typedef std::multimap<std::time_t, fs::path> result_set_t;
result_set_t result_set;

if ( fs::exists(someDir) && fs::is_directory(someDir))
{
  for( fs::directory_iterator dir_iter(someDir) ; dir_iter != end_iter ; ++dir_iter)
  {
    if (fs::is_regular_file(dir_iter->status()) )
    {
      result_set.insert(result_set_t::value_type(fs::last_write_time(dir_iter->path()), *dir_iter));
    }
  }
}
```

You can then iterate through `result_set`, and the mapped `boost::filesystem::path` entries will be in ascending order.

Comment: just a note here that if files are created/modified within the same second, their order is not guaranteed, as `std::time_t` is accurate to the second.

Comment: Please note http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#last_write_time. last_write_time gets path not status.
fs::last_write_time(dir_iter->path())

Comment: Can I sort the vector of paths in the last_write_time manner?

Comment: C++11 version with auto and make_iterator_range: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20925615/472308

Comment: C++17 introduced std::filesystem::last_write_time. You probably don't need boost to compile the example provided.