# Is {} a valid argument to pass to a function expecting an iterator (representing std::end() of some container)?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, iterator, boost-iterators

In [boost directory_iterator example - how to list directory files not recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923456/boost-directory-iterator-example-how-to-list-directory-files-not-recursive) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20925615/368896)) is the sample code

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <iostream>

...
using namespace boost::filesystem;

for(auto& entry : boost::make_iterator_range(directory_iterator(p), {}))
{
    std::cout << entry << "\n";
}
```

(`p` is of type `boost::filesystem::path`.)

Upon looking at the [documentation for `make_iterator_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html), I *think* the constructor being called is this one:

```
template< class ForwardTraversalIterator >
    iterator_range< ForwardTraversalIterator >
    make_iterator_range( ForwardTraversalIterator Begin,
                         ForwardTraversalIterator End );
```

If I'm right, then the second argument passed in the code example above, `{}`, seems to correspond to the end of whatever container is invisibly iterated over by the `directory_iterator`.

I've never seen this before.

Is it possible to construct the `end` iterator just by value-constructing such an iterator from the empty initializer list `{}`?  (Am I even phrasing this properly?)

I wouldn't mind having someone spell out what is going on under the hood, given that the **type** of the iterator so constructed must match the type of the first iterator (`directory_iterator(p)`).  (Is template argument deduction going on here?)

Comment: `{}` would be `directory_iterator{}`. Some iterator types use defaulted construct object at `end`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Does `boost::make_iterator_range` know that the second argument must be of type `directory_iterator` due to template argument deduction?  Come to think of it, from the very definition of `make_iterator_range` that I copied into this question, it's pretty obvious that it does.

Comment: It's worth noting that in VS 2013, this code will not build without an explicit `directory_iterator {}` as the argument - the plain `{}` does not compile.  Ahh, well.  I trust it's legal C++11 with just the plain `{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, it's valid.**

There's no template argument deduction beyond that which you already usually invoke: your first argument is of type `directory_iterator`, so the function is instantiated as such.

Following on from that, templates aside, now you are calling a function that takes two `directory_iterators`: the `{}` can *only* initialise a `directory_iterator` at that point, as that's what your function [template instance] takes. Hence, in this case, writing `{}` is functionally equivalent to writing `directory_iterator{}`.

If the `directory_iterator` could not be constructed from `{}`, your program would not compile.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the various overloads for [`boost::make_iterator_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html):

```
template< class ForwardTraversalIterator >
iterator_range< ForwardTraversalIterator >
make_iterator_range( ForwardTraversalIterator Begin, 
                     ForwardTraversalIterator End );

template< class ForwardRange >
iterator_range< typename range_iterator<ForwardRange>::type >
make_iterator_range( ForwardRange& r );

template< class ForwardRange >
iterator_range< typename range_iterator<const ForwardRange>::type >
make_iterator_range( const ForwardRange& r );

template< class Range >
iterator_range< typename range_iterator<Range>::type >
make_iterator_range( Range& r,
                     typename range_difference<Range>::type advance_begin,
                     typename range_difference<Range>::type advance_end );

template< class Range >
iterator_range< typename range_iterator<const Range>::type >
make_iterator_range( const Range& r, 
                     typename range_difference<const Range>::type advance_begin,
                     typename range_difference<const Range>::type advance_end );
```

Since your code has already specified that the first parameter is of type
`directory_iterator`, the only valid type for the second parameter is `directory_iterator`.  It's **unambiguous**.

Therefore, the type doesn't need to be specified.  `{}` is synonymous with `directory_iterator{}`, which is also synonymous with `directory_iterator()`.

Comment: This, in combination with @Jarod42's comment, would complete the answer.  Thanks!