# List files in a directory, not recursive, only files and no subdirectories, using C++

Tags: c++, boost

This is a follow up question to [boost directory_iterator example - how to list directory files not recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923456/boost-directory-iterator-example-how-to-list-directory-files-not-recursive).

The program

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    path const p(argc>1? argv[1] : ".");

    auto list = [=] { return boost::make_iterator_range(directory_iterator(p), {}); };

    // Save entries of 'list' in the vector of strings 'names'.
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    for(auto& entry : list())
    {
        names.push_back(entry.path().string());
    }

    // Print the entries of the vector of strings 'names'.
    for (unsigned int indexNames=0;indexNames<names.size();indexNames++)
    {
        std::cout<<names[indexNames]<<"\n";
    }
}
```

lists the files in a directory, not recursive, but also lists the names of the subdirectories. I only want to list the files and not the subdirectories.

How do I change the code to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> lists the files in a directory, not recursive, but also lists the
>   names of the subdirectories. I only want to list the files and not
>   subdirectories.

You may use `boost::filesystem::is_directory` to filter out directories and add only files:

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
for(auto& entry : list())
{
    if(!is_directory(entry.path()))
        names.push_back(entry.path().string());
}
```

Comment: Does it accept a `directory_entry` as an argument? According to [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#is_regular_file), it will accept either a `file_status` or a `path`.

Comment: `is_regular_file` will skip other things (for example, links).  There's an `is_directory` function that might be more appropriate.  Perhaps `is_directory(entry.path())`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, my mistake. Corrected

Comment: @BorisGlick, you are right. `is_directory` is more suitable for this. Thanks