# Getting segmentation fold when reading a list of files in a folder

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems, segmentation-fault

I'm using the code below, adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283546/cboostfilesystem-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-folder-in-which-the-fi) thread. I'm able to get the list of files in a folder, but I get segmentation fault at the end. Any idea why this is happening?
And is there a way to get std::string of the current file (complete path) in the for loop?

```
 boost::filesystem::path path("my_path");

 static void myfunction()
 {
     boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end_itr;
     // path is a static variable, defined somewhere else
     for(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator dir_iter(path); 
                                    dir_iter != end_itr;  ++dir_iter)
         if( boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(dir_iter->status()) )
         {
             // print


         }
  }
```

Comment: Can you show `end_itr` and `path`'s initializations?

Comment: updated. it should be initialized automatically.

Comment: i guess the snippet is not complete... a usual error is, to do something with dir_iter AFTER the loop, which then is invalid...

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you miss these lines:

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
fs::directory_iterator end_itr;
```

and try

```
cout << "entry: " << dir_iter->path().filename() << "\n";
cout << "entry path: " << dir_iter->path() << "\n";
```

in the loop

Refs: 
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_entry
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#class-path

Comment: I have the end_itr declaration. it is just giving me segmentation fault at the end of the loop