# find file starting with a certain string

Tags: c++, file

I wonder how to check If a file exist or not :

For Example I have many files :

```
Boba.txt
James.txt
Jamy.txt
Boby.txt
```

How can I check if the file starting with Bob exists ?

Comment: Are the filenames stored in a string array?

Comment: get the list of all files in directory, then check each file if it matches your prefix

Comment: Which version of C++ you are using? please post your code, if any!

Comment: @Marmik Oldest Version ,not c++11

Comment: @MarmiK This appears to ask about checking if a file starting with a prefix exists, which is quite different from the linked question.

Comment: @LeFlou That doesn't appear to have much to do with checking if a file exists, which is quite different and what this question is asking about.

Comment: Okay but you need to generate same string for checking file with different different possible names bob*.* or something like this [old post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569474/check-if-file-exists-with-wildcards-in-filename)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**, I'm assuming that you're on a Windows system and that the files are in the same directory.

You can use the [FindFirstFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) and [FindNextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx) functions to iterate through a directory. The prefix can be included in search term.

**Example**

```
std::string strSearch = "C:\\Some Directory\\Bob*";
WIN32_FIND_DATAA ffd;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileA(strSearch .c_str(), &ffd);

do
{
    std::string strFile = ffd.cFileName;
}
while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
```

*Proper error checking and how to deal with directories is left as an exercise for the reader.*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to do this within C++, the `boost::filesystem` library can be very helpful.  In that case, your problem can be solved by a variant of the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4283703/3585575).  In your case, you don't need a `std::multimap`, but can just use simple `std::string::find`.

Answer (score 0):

You could open a file with fopen as read only `"r"`. fopen will return a NULL pointer if the file does not exist. You can do this for any of the files needed by your program.

```
#include <cstdio>
int main ()
{
  FILE **pFile;
  pFile[0] = fopen ("Boba.txt","r");
  pFile[1] = fopen ("Boby.txt","r");
  if (pFile[0]!=NULL || pFile[1]!=NULL){
    printf("File starting with \"bob\" exists.");
  }
  else printf("File does not exist."); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Your code is writing to an invalid memory space: you haven't reserved space for pFile items, yet you're using them. The code is so small that it didn't cause any major problems, but it could in larger projects.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. It is fair. Thank you.