# List files in directory with same name

Tags: c++, filesystems

I have folder: **C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\SomeFolder**.

In the folder **"SomeFolder"** we have 10 files:

**abc.txt, abc1.txt, abc2.txt, abc3.txt, abc4.txt,**

**xyz.txt, xyz1.txt, xyz2.txt, xyz3.txt, xyz4.txt.**

Now let's say I want to display (list) all files which name start with **"abc"**.

It should look something like this:

```
std::string path = "path_to_directory"; //C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\SomeFolder
for (auto & p : fs::directory_iterator(path))
std::cout << p << std::endl;
```

But I need some kind of "filter".

Comment: Use regular expression library: std::regex http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050444/find-file-starting-with-a-certain-string

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774207/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-file-exist-using-standard-c-c11-c

Comment: I found that alredy, but that code doesn't work in my case:
   string directorys = directory + "\\abc*";
   std::string strSearch = directorys;
   WIN32_FIND_DATAA ffd;
   HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileA(strSearch.c_str(), &ffd);
   do
   {
    std::string strFile = ffd.cFileName;
   } while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `std::string::find`

```
for(auto& p: fs::directory_iterator(tempPath))
{
     std::string file_name = p.path().filename();
    if ( file_name.find("abc") == 0 )
    {
       std::cout << file_name  <<std::endl;
    }
}
```

[**`Demo Here`**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dda32112bdf00d32)

---

Can use  `std::regex` like following for some "complicated" pattern within the path

```
std::regex fileMatcher( tempPath + "/abc.*", 
                       // All files that begins with `abc` in current directory .
        std::regex_constants::ECMAScript | std::regex_constants::icase);

for(auto& p: fs::directory_iterator(tempPath))
if (std::regex_match (p.path().c_str() ,fileMatcher  ))
{
   std::cout << p <<std::endl;
}
```

[**`Demo Here`**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5aee4c448cce051)

<sup>*Might have to tweak for Windows Path. I don't have a latest compiler to check on windows*</sup>

Comment: "No instance of overloaded function std::regex match". Same as Josephnicholas

Comment: @Galik Thanks updated. Didn't see that was available as well.

Comment: @EnejUnterajter Updated , without `std::regex`. And std::regex will work as well see the demo link

Comment: @EnejUnterajter You need to include it `#include <regex>`

Comment: regex already included...

no suitable user-defined conversion from std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path to std::string exist?

Comment: @EnejUnterajter Could you check refer the attach link and fix your code ?
I gave a running demo as well, what else you want from us ? Write entire application for you ? These are normal error message, you should be able to fix those on your own.

Comment: will try to resolve it, thank you for your effort :)

Comment: Thank you all for your time and effort. Greetings. If anyone will need this:
   std::string path = your_directory;
   for (auto& p : fs::directory_iterator(your_directory))
   {
    std::string file_name = p.path().filename().string();
    if (file_name.find("abc") == 0)
    {
     std::cout << file_name << std::endl;
    }
   }

Answer (score -4):

Edited code:

```
    for(auto & p : fs::directory_iterator(path)){
        if (regex_match(p , regex("(abc)(.*)"))){
            cout <<p<< endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

it prints the file name starting with the string "abc"

Comment: I have never worked with regex before, however, the error says: "No instance of overloaded function std::regex match". Thank you for help anyway :)

Comment: you must #include <regex>. I am assuming you know your way from there. :) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/

Comment: Although the principle is right this code does not work.